# Is teshuva ever ineffective?

Tags: yom-kippur, repentance-teshuvah, maseches-rosh-hashana

[Rosh Hashana 17b](https://www.sefaria.org/Rosh_Hashanah.17b.10?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) quotes a Baraita

> [...] If one repents in the meantime, between Rosh HaShana and Yom Kippur, he is forgiven; if he does not repent in the meantime, then even if he later brings as offerings all the rams of Nebaioth in the world, which are of the best quality, **they do not forgive him in the Heavenly court**. This implies that once one’s sentence has been decreed, even repentance cannot alter it.

(The Gemara then clarifies that this is referring to an individual, not a community)

However, isn't it commonly accepted that teshuva for a sin is effective anytime* - whether before Yom Kippur, or after it, or even many years after its commission?

*(even if aseres ymei teshuva are the most opportune time for it)

Comment: This seems to discuss events that are decreed based on one's deeds, but not the essential idea of forgiveness and attachment to G-d through repentance. Sometimes it is too late to avoid the consequences of our actions, but it is never too late to learn from them.

Comment: How do you figure it means that, when the language of the Beraisa is "they do not forgive him [in the Heavenly court]"?

Comment: The discussion in Rosh Hashanah is about decrees of the Heavenly court. The discussion of essential repentance is in Yoma. It is clear that regarding one having a portion in the World To Come repentance is always effective: https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Repentance.4.6?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en

Comment: Still not sure why it would use language of "forgiveness" if it's only talking about decrees. ("Averting" a decree would seem more appropriate, rather than "forgive"). Also, where in Yoma itself do we see that repentance is always effective (your link was to the Rambam)?

Comment: The general theme of Teshuva as a mitzvah is discussed in Yoma, mostly from 85b and on. I brought Rambam for his analysis and synthesis of the topic. My point is that one can (and should) learn the context of a Talmudic discussion from the mesachta it is placed in. Indeed, laws are learned from the difference of placement between Bavli and Yerushalmi.

Comment: Once again, you're taking it too seriously. אין מזרזין אלא למזורזין - they motivate us to do Teshuva, they don't set rules of how Teshuva works. Same with Rambam.